# playframework issue ,Setting up Play fork run

Tags: playframework

I've created a simple application like the [tutorials](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Tutorials),and it works in activator UI .But when I run it in the terminal,it does not work ,it gives me an info

> [info] Setting up Play fork run ... (use Ctrl+D to cancel)

Comment: Could you add some error msg? Something?

Answer (score 5):

In `build.sbt` set `for in run` to `false`.

```
fork in run := false
```